# nested gridview get parent row

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I am using Nested GridViews where each row in the *gridview* has child gridView.
I am using **RowDataBound** Event of *Parent GridView*, to Binding *Child GridView*.
My Problem is that, how to get Parent GridView's Key on Child gridViews **RowDataBound** Event.

Below is example code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvParent" DataKeyNames="ID" runat="server" PageSize="1" AllowPaging="true" PagerSettings-Mode="NextPrevious" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SkinID="GVCenter" onrowdatabound="gvParent_RowDataBound">
   <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:GridView ID="gvChild"  DataKeyNames="ID" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeader="false" OnRowDataBound="gvChild_RowDataBound">
                  <Columns>
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" />                     
                  </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
    protected void gvParent_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            GridView gvChild= (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("gvChild");
            gvChild.DataSource = getChildObj();
            gvChild.DataBind();
        }
    }

   protected void gvChild_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            // Here I need to get the parent gridview Row Key
        }
    }
```

Hope the above code explains all the scenario.

Thanks in advance
Sandy

Comment: On RowDataBound for the parent GridView set the ID for the child grid to the row key.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvParent" DataKeyNames="ID" runat="server" PageSize="10" AllowPaging="true"
            PagerSettings-Mode="NextPrevious" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="gvParent_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="HdnID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvChild" DataKeyNames="ID" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                            ShowHeader="false" OnRowDataBound="gvChild_RowDataBound">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" />
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Code behind

```
protected void gvParent_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            GridView gvChild = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("gvChild");
            gvChild.DataSource = GetData();
            gvChild.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void gvChild_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string ID = ((HiddenField)e.Row.Parent.Parent.Parent.FindControl("HdnID")).Value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you will be able to track it normally, but I would embed ID field into the hidden field and put this hidden field under TemplateField,

```
<ItemTemplate> 
    <asp:HiddenField ID="idOfYourHiddenField" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />     
    <asp:GridView ID="gvChild"  DataKeyNames="ID" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeader="false" OnRowDataBound="gvChild_RowDataBound">                   
        <Columns>                      
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" />                                         
        </Columns>                 
    </asp:GridView>            
 </ItemTemplate>
```

this way you can get its value by going

```
gvChild.Parent.FindControl("idOfYourHiddenField");
```

Answer (score 2):

You Can Access The Parent of Child Gridview with the **Parent** Property.
You must be Try This:

```
 GridView gvChild = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("gvChild");
     Response.Write(gvChild.Parent);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to go 4 steps back and get the parent row like this

```
protected void gvChild_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                GridViewRow gvMasterRow = (GridViewRow)e.Row.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvParent" DataKeyNames="ID" runat="server" PageSize="1" AllowPaging="true"
PagerSettings-Mode="NextPrevious" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SkinID="GVCenter"
OnRowDataBound="gvParent_RowDataBound">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="gvChild" DataKeyNames="ID" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                ShowHeader="false" OnRowDataBound="gvChild_RowDataBound">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# (((IDataItemContainer)Container.Parent.Parent.Parent).DataItem as MyClass).MyProperty %>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```