# Row index from hierarchical gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have my gridview structure like this -

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gvTest" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
        Width="100%">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rule Name" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRuleName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RuleName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>


            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Source" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvSource" runat="server" ShowHeader="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                     <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:ImageButton ID="imgExpandSource" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/plus.png" onclick="imgExpandSource_Click"/>
                                  <asp:ImageButton ID="imgExpandSource1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Minus.png" onclick="imgExpandSource1_Click" Visible="false"/>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblSourceObjName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SourceObjName") %>'></asp:Label>                                       

                                    <asp:GridView ID="gvSourceObj" runat="server" ShowHeader="false" Visible="false">
                                    </asp:GridView>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>


            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Destination" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvDestination" runat="server" ShowHeader="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:ImageButton ID="imgExpand" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/plus.png" onclick="imgExpand_Click"/>
                                 <asp:ImageButton ID="imgExpand1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Minus.png" onclick="imgExpand1_Click" Visible="false"/>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDestObjName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DestObjName") %>'></asp:Label>                                      

                                    <asp:GridView ID="gvDestObj" runat="server" ShowHeader="false" Visible="false">
                                    </asp:GridView>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>


            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Service Group" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvServiceObject" runat="server" ShowHeader="false">
                    </asp:GridView>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Now I want to get the Row index of gvTest gridview on imgExpandSource link button's click event. So I tried with this code -

```
 protected void imgExpandSource_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {

        ImageButton imgExpandSource = sender as ImageButton;
        GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow)imgExpandSource.NamingContainer;
        int x = gvrow.RowIndex;
    }
```

But this is giving me gvSource gridviews row index. How can I get gvTest gridviews row index. Please some one help me.

Thanks
Gulrej

Comment: Following link will help you answer your question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008686/nested-gridview-get-parent-row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add some more levels to get the right naming contrainer:

```
protected void imgExpandSource_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{

    ImageButton imgExpandSource = sender as ImageButton;
    GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow)imgExpandSource
                             // GridViewRowRow of gvSource
                             .NamingContainer
                             // gvSource
                             .NamingContainer
                             // GridViewRow of gvTest
                             .NamingContainer;
    int x = gvrow.RowIndex;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Markus. Its working fine now. One question - what is the role of NamingContainer here?

Comment: @Gulrej: NamingContainer returns the parent container of a control that is used to build the unique id of a control (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer(v=vs.110).aspx). It should also work if you substitute `NamingContainer` by `Parent` in your sample. In this specific case the parents happen to be NamingContainers.